# Issue when using variable name in opening PDF (using Spire.Pdf)

Tags: c#, pdf

I need to check a permission ("EditContent") if it is enabled for the PDF on a path or not. I am using Spire.Pdf, when I try to call LoadFromFile with a variable name in argument it throws and error. However, if I am giving a hardcoded value it accepts and do the needful.

```
using Spire.Pdf;

public void PermissionOfPDF()
{
    string path = tempPath + fileName + ".pdf";
    PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument();
    Console.Write("\n Trying to load the PDF...\n");
    pdfDocument.LoadFromFile(path);
    Console.Write("\n Loaded the PDF...\n");
}
```

If i use hard coded path instead of pdfDocument.LoadFromFile(path), it opens and check for a particular permission.

I am not sure if would it be due to any coding issue or Spire has this issue.

**Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.**

Comment: Double check the value of `path` in the debugger - it will not be the same as your hardcoded value (`Path.Combine()` helps prevent missing slashes) & please add the exact exception you encounter.

Comment: Already crossed checked this out. 
I tried with @tempPath even, to make sure I am not missing out anything.

Expected Result: , due to ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: crossTable

Answer (score 0):

Use [Path.Combine()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?view=netframework-4.8) to make sure you have the correct number of slashes in all the right places:

```
string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(tempPath, fileName + ".pdf");
```

Comment: Already tried this out.
However getting same issue.

Expected Result: , due to ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: crossTable

However, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: A quick search brings up lots of people getting errors, and then being told to download a hotfix or patch...but then that only works for the PAID version.  I'd try a different library.

Comment: I have complete code written in Spire.PDF.
Quite difficult to port to other library.
Well thanks for the feedback.

If any one has any idea about free C# library for PDF, with which I can check if the permission ("EditContent") is enabled for or not.